# creation of a nested_attributes makes before_create not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm tried to create a User in the console doing:

```
2.2.1 :012 > u.save!
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('noc@co.co') LIMIT 1
  SQL (2.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "title", "time_zone", "company_id", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at", "activation_digest") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING "id"  [["id", 200], ["first_name", "Random"], ["last_name", "Dude"], ["email", "noc@co.co"], ["title", "CEO"], ["time_zone", "Stockholm"], ["company_id", 1], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$bHHA/JP5IMrucGUXRWMpsO8sInaouSqn48M.fDHpjGdvedu3Napra"], ["created_at", "2015-10-11 23:09:38.213109"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-11 23:09:38.213109"], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$WF3bUOtbC1gk4ZnX58cJZO5k7P7YV6wvhmwz7EErTdvIseNuy0oyq"]]
2.2.1 :013 > u.activation_token
 => "vKrs0jtvZRiyU-YVE-aPXw"
```

now when I try to create a user the before_create doesn't work, I tried changing it to before_validation and that didn't work either.

The user is a nested attribute from companies, and is created in Companies#new.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
  before_save   :downcase_email
  before_create :create_activation_digest
```

now when I do @user.activation_token it returns nil. Here's the console log from when I try it on the app:

```
Started POST "/companies" for ::1 at 2015-10-12 01:31:47 +0200
Processing by CompaniesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZTEtGR2Dd1FDDYm9j4/SiqSTP646R8gctFx4aJHM9QDP+RQky8SG6gkomLbf+E+LgMi+aah1YOhCkUsg3uSYoQ==", "company"=>{"time_zone"=>"Stockholm", "users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"first_name"=>"swaga", "last_name"=>"swaga", "email"=>"swaga@wkoa.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}, "name"=>"swaga"}, "commit"=>"Create Company"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('swaga@wkoa.com') LIMIT 1
  SQL (7.1ms)  INSERT INTO "companies" ("name", "time_zone", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "swaga"], ["time_zone", "Stockholm"], ["created_at", "2015-10-11 23:31:47.380530"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-11 23:31:47.380530"]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("first_name", "last_name", "email", "password_digest", "activation_digest", "company_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["first_name", "swaga"], ["last_name", "swaga"], ["email", "swaga@wkoa.com"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$3GsPACTg5HPodiqdedsCvu52N64BEE3/fA77p.oBHAhM51zCSzUV."], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$75y9jP.eZxmWI1KjHZrg3.DuB5GSwiS2UsaQdtV25ClBHDi.z4Pte"], ["company_id", 8], ["created_at", "2015-10-11 23:31:47.390462"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-11 23:31:47.390462"]]
   (6.7ms)  COMMIT
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."company_id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 8]]
  Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer (7.8ms)

UserMailer#account_activation: processed outbound mail in 29.2ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 380ms (ActiveRecord: 16.9ms)

ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"swaga@wkoa.com", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]:
```

now I see that the activation_digest is returned, so I think the issue is literarily just the before_create not working? Which is weird because then it shouldn't be able to create an activation digest as the two are connected:

```
# Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
def create_activation_digest
  self.activation_token  = User.new_token
  self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
end
```

Comment: can you post the `account_activations_controller.rb` file? also the corresponding view file.

Comment: Also, post your `routes.rb` file please.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"swaga@wkoa.com", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]:
```

Seems like, in your view, you are calling `edit_account_activation_path` without the `id` param and that's creating the problem for you. Try to send the `user.id` as a parameter in the `edit_account_activation_path` call.

Something like this:

```
edit_account_activation_path(user.email, user.id)
```

That should fix your issue.